# CORS issue between Laravel backend and Vue frontend hosted on Plesk with Nginx

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, cors, plesk

I'm facing a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) problem while attempting to authenticate users from my Vue frontend to my Laravel backend, and subsequently, a Flutter mobile app. The backend API works seamlessly via Postman, and the Flutter app operates without any CORS issues. However, when attempting to log in from the Vue frontend, I encounter the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend-api-url/login' from origin 'https://vue-frontend-url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Previously, when hosted on cPanel with Apache, this setup functioned correctly, but after migrating to Plesk with Nginx, I encounter these CORS conflicts.

Here's a summary of the setup:

- Laravel backend API
- Vue frontend for an admin panel
- Flutter mobile app
- Previous successful functionality with cPanel and Apache
- Current issues with Plesk and Nginx

Steps taken so far:

- Verified the backend API works with Postman
- Checked Flutter app's functionality without CORS issues
- Explored potential CORS configurations in Laravel and Vue

I've reviewed various solutions involving CORS headers in Laravel, Nginx configurations, and Vue Axios settings but haven't found a resolution yet. Any insights or guidance on resolving this CORS conflict specifically within the Plesk and Nginx environment would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create middleware called corsHandler:

```
    class corsHandler
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse) $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    }
}
```

and in your kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
...,
\App\Http\Middleware\corsHandler::class
]
```

and:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
...,
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\corsHandler::class
]
```

Comment: But why did this happen in the first place?

Comment: Why not use https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#cors ?

Comment: I already used it and it didn't help, thank you.